# ServerSocket is connected with Client socket....but server is not receiving OutputStream of ClientSocket...and compiler is showing no error

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, readline

I am making a simple chat program in java....i cant find the source problem in client side code ....i also has tested the server with another chat client and it is working ....but not with my Client....the chat program is very simple ....the client send the string and server receives it and send back to all its clients and clients displays it in incoming TextArea..

the server is showing it got connection with my client socket ...but when i send the string it is not receiving it..and i am unable to find the problem

it is working with other chat client.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class chatbox {

    JFrame fr = new JFrame("Chat");
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    JPanel pnl2 = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrl;
    JTextArea tarea;
    JTextField fld;
    JLabel lb;
    JLabel lbchat;
    JButton btn;

    Socket socket;
    PrintWriter writer;
    BufferedReader reader;

    btnListener BL = new btnListener();

    void guibuilder() {
        fr.setSize(400, 400);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);

        fld = new JTextField(20);
        lb = new JLabel("Message :");
        lbchat = new JLabel("Chat Box");

        tarea = new JTextArea(400, 500);
        tarea.setLineWrap(true);
        scrl = new JScrollPane(tarea);

        btn = new JButton("Send");
        btn.addActionListener(BL);

        pnl.add(lb);
        pnl.add(fld);
        pnl.add(btn);
        pnl2.add(lbchat);
        pnl2.add(scrl);

        fr.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, pnl);
        fr.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, pnl2);

        setUpNet();
        Thread readerThread = new Thread(new SR());
        readerThread.start();

    }

    void setUpNet() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            System.out.println("networking established");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    class btnListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {

                writer.print(fld.getText());
                writer.flush();

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            fld.setText("");
            fld.requestFocus();

        }
    }//inner class end  

    class SR implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            String message;

            try {
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("read" + message);
                    tarea.append(message + "\n");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }//inner class end

}

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        chatbox c = new chatbox();
        c.guibuilder();

    }
}
```

Comment: You are reading lines, with `readLine()`, but you aren't writing lines, with `print()`. Use `println()`.

Comment: @user207421....it worked. But why print() was not working.

Comment: Err, because of what I already said?

Comment: @user207421...i mean, print() also write the line of string..println() only writes the string in next line...why the server's  bufferedReader not even reading a single line of String.

Answer (score 0):

Credits : user207421

I was using print() of PrintWriter stream instead of println(). As the server was using readlLine() of BufferedReader the print() was not working .